# Bigcommerce Repeating url

Tags: url, seo, duplicates, bigcommerce

So this is a two-parter.

1. I'm doing SEO for a client using Bigcommerce and Screaming Frog is returning some crazy URLs. Here is an example:

> ~/shop/product_images/product_images/product_images/uploaded_images/img-email.jpg

There are thousands of these. with `/product_images` being repeated ranging from only once, to up to dozens and dozens of times. This is duplicated over the product categories as well ie

> ~/shop/kitchen/countertops/product_images/...

2. The weirdest part about it is that they all (including `~/shop/product_images/img-email.jpg`) resolve to the home page, with a `200` response no less. Not a `404` or a `301/302` redirect or anything.

Feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find anything in the dashboard that seems to make sense.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all your links. May be you have errors. Something like `product_images` instead of `/product_images` i.e. missing slash. You can find this info as Inlinks and Outlinks in Screaming Frog.

Comment: This is basically it. The template the client bought used a relative link to img-email.jpg which broke pretty much everywhere. Still not sure why those links were returning a 200 but who cares, they don't exist anymore anyway! Thanks